# How to view/read a TIFF image file using Apache Commons Sanselan/Imaging in Java?

Tags: java, apache, tiff

I am new to Apache Commons Imaging (and StackOverflow as well), and I'm unable to find any good resource to learn how to use Imaging. There's the documentation, but there's a serious lack of examples/tutorials to explain what is happening.

Objective: I want to make a TIFF image viewer (display) using Apache Commons Imaging. But I've been unable to find any example code or something close to it, or even a single related tutorial.

Problems in code:
1) I'm not so sure if the code below is the one I want for my task.
2) I don't know how to test the 'second' class using the main() method.

I'm unable to write the main() method to test the following class:

```
public class second {
    public static BufferedImage imageReadExample(final File file)
            throws ImageReadException, IOException {
        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        // set optional parameters if you like
        params.put(SanselanConstants.BUFFERED_IMAGE_FACTORY,
                new ManagedImageBufferedImageFactory());

        // params.put(ImagingConstants.PARAM_KEY_VERBOSE, Boolean.TRUE);

        // read image
        final BufferedImage image = Sanselan.getBufferedImage(file, params);

        return image;
    }

    public static class ManagedImageBufferedImageFactory implements
            IBufferedImageFactory {

        @Override
        public BufferedImage getColorBufferedImage(final int width, final int height,
                final boolean hasAlpha) {
            final GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            final GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
            final GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            return gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height,
                Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        }

        @Override
        public BufferedImage getGrayscaleBufferedImage(final int width, final int height,
                final boolean hasAlpha) {
            return getColorBufferedImage(width, height, hasAlpha);
        }
    }
}
```

I took the above code from one of the examples available on the Apache website (ImageReadExample) from [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/ImageReadExample.java)

To test the 'second' class, I wrote the main method as follows:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final File file = new File("someimage.TIF");

        try {
            final BufferedImage image = second.imageReadExample(file);
        } catch (ImageReadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that the above main method is just a naive attempt, since I have little idea how to test the 'second' class.
I want to display the TIFF image whose path I write in the File constructor.

When I run this code, it throws this exception:

```
org.apache.sanselan.ImageReadException: Missing expected field: 277 (0x115: Samples Per Pixel): 
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffDirectory.findField(TiffDirectory.java:186)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffImageParser.getBufferedImage(TiffImageParser.java:463)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffDirectory.getTiffImage(TiffDirectory.java:163)
at org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffImageParser.getBufferedImage(TiffImageParser.java:441)
at org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan.getBufferedImage(Sanselan.java:1264)
at org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan.getBufferedImage(Sanselan.java:1255)
at bisag.second.imageReadExample(second.java:29)
at bisag.test.main(test.java:22)
```

Here, 'bisag' is my package name which contains classes 'test'and 'second'.

Need corrections in the code and help in understanding what to do and how to implement the code. Thanks in advance!

P.S. : Since I only have Sanselan (0.97 incubator) in my PC (and not Imaging 1.0 SNAPSHOT), I modified the code according to Sanselan. So, the code is essentially the same.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there a problem with the code you have posted? Describe the problem you are trying to solve. Do you get an exception? Unexpected behaviour? In case, what did you expect the code to do? :-)

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly. Thank you! :)

Comment: It seems to me your code is mostly good, however, the problem seems to be your sample TIFF file. Can you attach or link to that file? PS: I also recommend following Java code conventions, like using capitalized class names (ie. `Test` and `Second`), it will make others more comfortable reading your code. :-)